# Set transparent raster values with Python

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, transparency-opacity

I have loaded a few raster layers in QGIS 2.18.

I select a few of them. Next, I run the script:

The first option

```
#Change properties selected layers
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers(True)
for layer in selectedLayers:
    print layer.name()
    pixel = QgsRasterTransparency().initializeTransparentPixelList(255,255,255)
    layer.renderer().setRasterTransparency(pixel)
    layer.triggerRepaint()

 print "Finish"
```

Property of the selected layers has not changed.

The second option

```
#Change properties selected layers
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers(True)
for layer in selectedLayers:
    print layer.name()
    rasterTransparency = layer.renderer().rasterTransparency()
    listPixels = []
    pixel = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()    
    pixel.red = 255
    pixel.green = 255
    pixel.blue = 255
    pixel.percentTransparent = 100
    listPixels.append(pixel)
    rasterTransparency.setTransparentSingleValuePixelList(listPixels)

#Refresh map
for layMap in qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    layMap.triggerRepaint()

print "Finish"
```

Property of the selected layers has not changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [transparentThreeValuePixelList()](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterTransparency.html#a1acd2da1ce397886a20298f4abe0f2e4) method instead of the [transparentSingleValuePixelList()](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterTransparency.html#ab164740a19a58edb9a56ae919f424a5e). Making this slight change to your code should work:

```
selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers(True)
for layer in selectedLayers:
    rasterTransparency = layer.renderer().rasterTransparency()
    listPixels = []
    pixel = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentThreeValuePixel()
    pixel.red = 255
    pixel.green = 255
    pixel.blue = 255
    pixel.percentTransparent = 100
    listPixels.append(pixel)
    rasterTransparency.setTransparentThreeValuePixelList(listPixels)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]